# Bootstrap 4: Layout does not render properly in browser

Tags: html, layout, bootstrap-4, harp

I have created basic static website project with harp.js. Project does compiles successfully with no errors and I have added required files and dependencies for bootstrap 4.Problem is my template layout does not render properly.

**Here is my layout html.**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
<%- partial("partial/_header") %>
    <%- yield %>
        <%- partial("partial/_footer") %>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
                    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**_header partial view html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Learning Bootstrap 4</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</nav>
```

I am getting same output in every browser.
[image: Here is the output]

[JsFiddle for problem](https://jsfiddle.net/Ahsan9981/cjhnsouf/1/)
Can any point out what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you adding any other CSS files in the page which could have affected the layou?

Comment: @KK , no I only have one bootstrap.min.css yet.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with whatever code you have provided. Can you create a jsfiddle and try to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I am creating a fiddle for it.

Comment: you can check it here https://jsfiddle.net/Ahsan9981/cjhnsouf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `navbar-expand` on nav element. Check the updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cjhnsouf/2/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-faded">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Learning Bootstrap 4</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
</nav>
```